# mysql where statement date issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

hope someone can help,

What i`m trying to do is pull all results from the database for any given month,
Is the possible using a mysql query only (no php).

Im using a template app with the only access i have is through i mysql where statement, So i need to work out from "2013-04-01" what the month is and grab it if its the one i want.

The code below works but obviously ties me too the 2013 year.

```
  `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Display_Date => 2013-04-01 AND Display_Date <= 2013-04-30 LIMIT 10`
```

Comment: is the display_date column a datetime column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table_name 
WHERE 
    MONTH(Display_Date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND YEAR(Display_Date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

**reference**

- [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
- [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Comment: Oh my god!, Its that easy. i spent hours coming up with my effort!many thanks. So the code below would get my april 2004 correct? its difficult to try as the database currently only has entries for april:SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE MONTH( Display_Date )=4
AND YEAR( Display_Date )=2013
LIMIT 10